# defined_names is not working even if i am having defined cell range in my excel worksheet

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

i tried running the following code and i’m facing an error everytime i run it. I’m using jupyter notebook to run it. My current excel file named ‘Saved_Pivots’ is of xlsx type created on WPS.

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl import *
from openpyxl.styles import NamedStyle

workbook = load_workbook('Saved_Pivots.xlsx')

worksheet = workbook.active
w=worksheet.defined_names['efd']
w
```

I'm experiencing the following error:-

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-189-aaf0edbea060> in <module>
      7 
      8 worksheet = workbook.active
----> 9 w=worksheet.defined_names['efd']
     10 w

AttributeError: 'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'defined_names'
```

Comment: I had already created a cell range named 'efd' in the excel file. But the openpyxl is still not able to locate it.

Answer (score 0):

I understood where i was wrong. defined_names function works with workbook instead of worksheet.

So i tried using this below & it works.

```
w=workbook.defined_names['efd']
```